# Unable to activate Windows Store app. The activation request failed with error 'Access is denied'

Tags: c#, uwp

UWP program that used to work fine does not want to start. When starting the app from Visual Studio 2017 the error message is:

> Unable to activate Windows Store app '{guid-name}'. The activation request failed with error 'Access is denied'.

Windows Event Viewer displays the following error:

> Activation for {guid-name} failed. Error code: Access is denied.. Activation phase: COM ActivateExtension

The app deploys successfully, but then trying to start it (with or without debugging) it fails. When trying to start from Start menu, nothing happens when I click the app icon, but when trying to start from Visual Studio it produces an error message box. How to find out what is actually wrong?

I have tried the following:

- Rebooting computer
- Clean solution
- Uninstall the deployed app
- Delete bin folder
- Compile with .NET Native toolchain
- The solution is on C: drive
- Change package name
- Change to release profile and back to debug

When I try to create a new UWP app, it works fine, so this is most likely solution-specific error, not something wrong in the computer itself.

Answer (score 5):

Usually this happens when there is an App with the same GUID as the one you are trying to Install/Debug. I would try to find the existing App, uninstall it, and try to deploy/debug again.

Comment: Or just change your own guid (?)

Comment: I tried changing the package name, but that didn't help. And I also tried uninstalling the previous version of the app and cleaning all the directories, including the C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Packages\{appname} -one. That did't help either.

Comment: There are several Id/Guids, do look around in the Settings and Properties.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when creating a blank Xamarin.Forms app targeting UWP. The solution was to create an exception for my app in F-Sscure which would otherwise block it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message to this, but my error was that a Nuget package had a different package version to my App.

- "App" had dependency "B" version .14
- Dependency "A" had dependency "B" version .13

i don't think this will solve this particular issue but it solved mine and i couldn't find  solution to this anywhere.